# Replace two double quote with one double quote

Tags: linux, bash, awk, replace

Thank you all for your time.

I am trying to replace two double quotes with one double quote.

for example, I have the below data:

```
1,2,3,4,"abc""
```

And I want it to be:

```
1,2,3,4,"abc"
```

Here is the awk command I am using, but it is not working:

```
cat sample.csv | awk '{ sub(/"\*""/, "\*", $5)}'
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4):

To replace all `""` by `"` with sed:

```
sed 's/""/"/g' file
```

Comment: hi! Thanks a lot for your answer. It almost worked with me. it removed the two double quotes but it didn't replace it with one. so in the end, this is what I got: 1,2,3,4,"abc

Comment: @Dr.Bake that is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`, just remove the last `"`:

```
sed 's/"$//' sample.csv
```

Similar logic with `awk` using `sub()`:

```
awk 'sub("\"$", "")' sample.csv
```

**Example:**

```
% sed 's/"$//' <<<'1,2,3,4,"abc""' 
1,2,3,4,"abc"

% awk 'sub("\"$", "")' <<<'1,2,3,4,"abc""'
1,2,3,4,"abc"
```

Comment: hello,thank you for your example, but it didn't work with me :)

Comment: In OP's question there is a space in the end after the two double quotes `1,2,3,4,"abc"" `. That might be why it wouldn't work. The awk could be changed to `awk 'sub(/\"\"/,"\"")'` to replace the two double quotes with a single one.

Answer (score 0):

If  you like adventure, you could try something like below. This balances quotes around the text :

```
$ cat 39316179
 1,2,3,4,"abc""
 1,2,""4",3,"""abc""" # Notice irregular quoting.
 1,2,4,"3"",""""abc""""

$ sed -E 's/"+([^"]*)"+/"\1"/g' 39316179
 1,2,3,4,"abc"
 1,2,"4",3,"abc"
 1,2,4,"3","abc"
```

**Explanation**

- `"+` means looks for double quotes one or more times
- `([^"]*)` means look for look for `not double quotes`(`[^"]`) any number of times(`*`). The surrounding `()` means we wish to re-use this pattern that was matched later.
- In the substitution part, we place beginning double quote, the part that we stored in `()` in the previous step and the ending double quote.

Comment: Hi! thank you for your help, but can you please explain your answer further?

Comment: @Dr.Bake: Explanation added

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed 's/"\+/"/g'
```

`+` means more than 1 occurence of a given character

I have made a bigger mess of your example just to show it works on any number of consecutive occurences of given character, in this case `"`

Original file:

```
$ cat d.txt
1,2,3,4,"abc""
"1"",""2""","""3"","4",""abc""
""""1"","""2"",""""3"","""4"","abc""
"""1"""",""2"","""3""",""""4"""",""""abc"""""
```

Result:

```
$ cat d.txt | sed 's/"\+/"/g'
1,2,3,4,"abc"
"1","2","3","4","abc"
"1","2","3","4","abc"
"1","2","3","4","abc"
```

Comment: `\+` is a non-standard extension to POSIX BREs, a portable alternative would be `\{1,\}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '1,2,3,4,"abc""' | awk '{sub(/c""/,"c\"")}1'

1,2,3,4,"abc"
```

What it does? It removes the very last quotation mark. Perhaps a better way is to put it like this:

awk 'sub(/"$/,"")' Then we don't have to bother whith escaping anything.

Comment: Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. Comments would help create searchable content.